# Ubuntu 22.04 NFS server timeout?

Tags: nfs

I use an Ubuntu NFS server.  I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 which only supports NFS over TCP.  I am seeing the server close connections after 10 minutes, which my client is not handling correctly.  Where is this timeout configured?

Comment: The default timeout for a TCP established session should be very long (5 days). I don't see anything close to 10 minutes, except for `nf_conntrack_generic_timeout`, which shouldn't apply in your case. Anyway, try this `grep . /proc/sys/net/netfilter/*` and look [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/nf_conntrack-sysctl.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the timeout, it is in the kernel code:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.19/net/sunrpc/svc_xprt.c#L41

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.19/net/sunrpc/svc_xprt.c#L978

It appears that this timeout is not configurable.